# JavaScript add class depending on current URL

Tags: javascript, css, url

For my website navigation I need to add the class 'active' to the li element depending on if it matches the current URL.

Nav HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tagged/Review">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tagged/First_Look">First Looks</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tagged/Commentary">Commentaries</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tagged/Walkthrough">Walkthroughs</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tagged/Achievement">Achievements</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you using any javascript libraries or just vanilla js?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Could you explain…?

Comment: "JavaScript libraries" meaning something like jQuery, Prototype, Dojo, MooTools, YUI, RightJS, etc...

Comment: I think I may have jQuery, but not entirely sure.

Comment: jQuery, Prototype and Mootools are examples of javascript libraries. They often help simplify javascript coding. Vanilla javascript would be javascript without any libraries.

Comment: If I could use vanilla JavaScript that would be great, although I do use jQuery.

Comment: Try running this code: `alert($().jquery)` - if you get a messagebox with a value such as '1.5.2', you are running jquery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use "pure" (*"vanilla"*) JavaScript, use the following code(assuming that `<ul id="nav">` exists):

```
window.onload = function() { 
    var all_links = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a"),
        i=0, len=all_links.length,
        full_path = location.href.split('#')[0]; //Ignore hashes?

    // Loop through each link.
    for(; i<len; i++) {
        if(all_links[i].href.split("#")[0] == full_path) {
            all_links[i].className += " active";
        }
    }
}
```

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var full_path = location.href.split("#")[0];
    $("#nav a").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.prop("href").split("#")[0] == full_path) {
            $this.addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a quick note - this will only work if the href of the links is a full path i.e. http://example.com/tagged/Review.

`if(all_links[i].href.split('#')[0].substr(-1 * full_path.length) == full_path)` would match just the relative url.

Comment: @AdamHutchinson Actually, not. I am using the `href` property (jQuery: `.prop("href")`, which returns a parsed path. So, if the link at `http://so.com/dir/file` contained `href="../bar"`, the link will be interpreted as `http://so.com/bar`.

Comment: This worked as is, however it applied it self to the a element instead of the li element.

Comment: Ahh, I assumed that .href would return the actual 'href' attribute of the link. I should've tested it before I made that assumption! Ignore my previous comment OP.

Comment: @KristianMatthews - just use `all_links[i].parentNode.className += 'active'`

Comment: @KristianMatthews To add the class to the `<li>` element, use `all_links[i].parentNode.className += " active";`, or (jQuery) `This.parent().addClass("active");`

Answer (score 1):

I think, in this case, is better change in server side.

Using javascript you can do:

```
var target = 0;
switch( window.location.pathname )
{
    case "/tagged/Review":
        target = 1;
        break;

    case "/tagged/First_Look":
        target = 2;
        break;
    /* add other cases */
}

document.getElementById("nav").getElementByTagName("li")[target].classList.add("active");
```

Put the code after loaded DOM.

If jquery, you can use:

```
var target = 0;
switch( window.location.pathname )
{
    case "/tagged/Review":
        target = 1;
        break;

    case "/tagged/First_Look":
        target = 2;
        break;
    /* add other cases */
}

$($("#nav li")[target]).addClass("active");
```

**EDIT**

window.onload or $.ready is the way to know if the document is loaded.

Comment: This would work, but seems like a very long winded way of doing it as you will have to change the javascript whenever the menu changes.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with DOM, if you explain that to me that would be great, thanks.