# jQuery add class depending on current URL to semanti-ui dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url, semantic-ui

I need to add the class 'active' to links depending on it matching the current URL. I made that work using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8185746/2505808) but i need to make it work also for dropdown links. This is the markup I'm using:

```js
var full_path = location.href.split("#")[0];
$("#nav a").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.prop("href").split("#")[0] == full_path) {
    $this.addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav" class="ui large secondary inverted pointing menu">
  <a class="toc item">
    <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="index.php" class="item">Home</a>
  <a href="serverinfo.php" class="item">Server information</a>
  <div class="ui pointing dropdown link item">
    <span class="text">Community</span>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="item" href="forum.php">Forum</a>
      <a class="item" href="market.php">Item Market</a>
      <a class="item" href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
      <a class="item" href="support.php">Support</a>
      <a class="item" href="helpdesk.php">Helpdesk</a>
      <a class="item" href="houses.php">Houses</a>
      <a class="item" href="deaths.php">Deaths</a>
      <a class="item" href="killers.php">Killers</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui pointing dropdown link item">
    <span class="text">Shop</span>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="item" href="buypoints.php">Buy points</a>
      <a class="item" href="shop.php">Shop offers</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui pointing dropdown link item">
    <span class="text">Guilds<?php if ($config['guildwar_enabled'] === true) { ?> & Wars<?php } ?></span>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="item" href="guilds.php">Guilds</a>
      <?php if ($config[ 'guildwar_enabled']===t rue) { ?>
      <a class="item" href="guildwar.php">Guild Wars</a>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui pointing dropdown link item">
    <span class="text">Library</span>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="item" href="downloads.php">Downloads</a>
      <a class="item" href="changelog.php">Changelog</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right item">
    <a id="loginButton" class="ui blue inverted button">
      <?php if (user_logged_in()===t rue) { echo 'Account'; } else { echo 'Log in';}?>
    </a>
    <div class="ui fluid transition login popup">
      <?php if (user_logged_in()===t rue) { include 'layout/widgets/loggedin.php'; } else { include 'layout/widgets/login.php'; } ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (user_logged_in()===f alse) { echo '<a class="ui green inverted button" href="register.php">Register</a>'; } ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, dropdowns are using `<span>` tags, and they are showing the text of the dropdown. Is there a way to put the "name" of the link into that span when it's active ?

Comment: What do you mean the _name_ of the link when it's active? So the top level span shouldn't show `community` initially? Instead, it should show the name of the matching active link, but only if it matches the page URL?

Comment: You could then just use another if statement to replace the content of your  span? `if ($this.prop("href").split("#")[0] == full_path) {  
      $('.ui.dropdown span').text($('ui.dropdown .active').text());  
    }`

Comment: That kind of worked, but look what's happening [on this image](http://i.imgur.com/xlMS7Js.png)

Comment: In the semantic ui dropdown options, there is the option to initialize it with `action: 'select'` - which will still allow most functionality but won't try to change the value of the text field itself. At the place where you first initialize your dropdown you should add this option by running `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({action: "select"})`