# Add class to div if url for image in this div is the same as current page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list (`<li>`) of items that looks like that:

```
<div class="image_frame">
     <div>
          <div>
               <a href="link 1"><img /></a>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I would like to add additional class to `div` with image_frame if current page URL is the same as item URL (I just want this specific `div` to be highlighted if item link is the same as the page I've visited).

I've found solution that is really close, but it adds class to current link, not to parent `div` but 3 levels above.

[JavaScript add class depending on current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185746/javascript-add-class-depending-on-current-url)

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
"use strict";

let div = document.querySelector('.image_frame');
let ref = 'http://domains.com/link-1/'; // delete this, it's just for test
// let ref = window.location.href; // insert this
let url = div.querySelector('img').parentNode.href;

if (url === ref) {
    div.className += ' new_class';
    console.log('DIV class was changed to: ' + div.className);
}
```

```html
<div class="image_frame">
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="http://domains.com/link-1/"><img /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```